# Spring JPA - Ignore a field only in persistence

Tags: spring, jackson

I have a field called `password` which can be received by endpoint. But it cannot be sent back in response or persisted in Database

The class is as follows -

```
public class ShortURL {

@Pattern(regexp="^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]")
private String url;

@Size(min=8,max=16)
@Transient
private String password = null;

private boolean isPasswordProtected = false;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public boolean isPasswordProtected() {
    return isPasswordProtected;
}
public void setPasswordProtected(boolean isPasswordProtected) {
    this.isPasswordProtected = isPasswordProtected;
}
public ShortURL(
        @Pattern(regexp = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]") String url,
        @Size(min = 8, max = 16) String password, boolean isPasswordProtected) {
    super();
    this.url = url;
    this.password = password;
    this.isPasswordProtected = isPasswordProtected;
}
```

`@Transient` works properly. But adding the `@JsonIgnore` after `@Transient` causes problems -

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class java.lang.String]; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
No fallback setter/field defined for creator property 'password'"
```

How do I achieve my intentions?

Comment: Any reason not to have separate object for controller where you can use jackson annotations and domain object with JPA annotations? Having mixed annotation for representation layer and persistent in one class looks horrible to me

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your Jackson version.

Before version 1.9, you could add `@JsonIgnore` to the getter of `password` and add `@JsonProperty` to the setter of the `password` field.

[Recent versions](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html) of Jackson provide `READ_ONLY` and `WRITE_ONLY` annotation arguments for `@JsonProperty`, something like this:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private String password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use @JsonIgnore to let jackson ignore it during sending the user response but. There are certain best practices you should follow.

Never expose the Entities directly to the endpoint instead its better to have a wrapper i.e DTO that translates your entity to the required response.
For eg. in your case

```
    public class ShortURL {
    @Pattern(regexp="^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]")
    private String url;
    @Size(min=8,max=16)
    private String password;
    private boolean isPasswordProtected;
    }
```

//here is the dto in which you can create a parameterised constructor and 
accordingly invoke it based on the fields you want to set.

```
      public class ShortURLDTO {
        private String url;
    public ShortURLDTO(String url){
    this.url=url
    }
 }
```